# Cannot add Service class [class ...WebService]. It is not a Service

Tags: grails, service

I have domain class with the name webService. When I'm trying to test it every time I get the same exception  Cannot add Service class [class ...WebService]. It is not a Service!

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Cannot add Service class [class ...WebService]. It is not a Service!
    at grails.test.mixin.services.ServiceUnitTestMixin.mockService(ServiceUnitTestMixin.groovy:46)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension$FixtureType$FixtureMethodInterceptor.intercept(JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension.java:145)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
|Completed 1 spock test, 1 failed in 0m 0s
```

I'm just trying to find some workaround maybe somebody have idea?

Comment: Is your class located in the service folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "Service" appended to a class is reserved for [Grails Services](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html). This is a part of the convention over configuration principle. All you have to do is rename your domain class. For example, you could call it WebSrv.

Comment: @SilverJay If the database table needs to be called `web_service` then you can rename the domain class and then use a `mapping` closure to override the default table name. Grails is very much designed to work by convention, and while there may be ways to configure things that break the conventions, sooner or later you'll find a plugin or something that assumes the conventions are followed and things will break inexplicably.  Far simpler to stick to the conventions in the first place.